# laravel 8 migration deletes worldcities table

Tags: laravel, migrate

I have a table called worldcities that has all the cities on this planet, but everytime I migrate:fresh --seed then all tables are deleted including this one. Also, it takes forever to put the cities back since it's about 1gb.

What would be the best way to use ***php artisan migrate:fresh --seed*** without also deleting the worldcities table? I have tried many options, but none is working yet.

I read something about --ignore=worldcities, but that doesn't work with fresh. So it's not taking me anywhere this far.

Comment: Why are you using `:fresh`in the first place?
You can run `php artisan migrate --seed` if you do not need to recreate the entire schema.

Comment: Yeah, `migrate:fresh` or `migrate:refresh` will by definition drop all tables. If this `world_cities` table is the "first" migration, then you could do something like `php artisan migrate:rollback --step=X`, where `X` is the number of steps minus 1, to avoid that one, or something similar.

Comment: The other option would be something like a Console command to create and seed this table, which would have to be run separately from the Migrations and Seeders. etc. Just a couple thoughts. Also, I hope this goes without saying, but I hope you're running this refresh locally only; running this on a Production environment will nuke the whole database, which is a very destructive process.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `migrate:fresh` you can use `migrate:refresh`, which uses `down()` method of the migration.

So in `down` method comment dropping table: `Schema::dropIfExists()`,

Then in `up` method, check that table is already exists or not:

```php
if (Schema::hasTable('table_name')) {
    return;
}
```

For seeding simply check that record exists or not, for preventing duplication. Or for fewer query, just create if table doesn't have any records.